# Trying to write a PDF directly to the response header in my API

Tags: response-headers

I'm using golang:

```
 w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
 w.WriteHeader(200) 
 err = a.Core.WritePDFToHeader(w) ...
```

I'm generating the pdf then writing it directly to the response writer. It's hitting my API and there's no errors.

When I call my API I'm getting a correct response back:

1. Content-Length: 1122
2. Content-Type: application/pdf
3. Date: XXXXXXXX
4. Vary: Origin

But it's not actually 'downloading' in the browser, I can see the raw data in my response:

%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <</Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /Resources 2 0 R /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj

I'm out of ideas as to why this wouldn't work, I hate anything origin related but I have a funny feeling it may be something to do with the origin config. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need it, maybe something else is wrong. That should be enough.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    file_name := os.Args[1]
    fileD, err := os.Open(file_name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    file_bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(fileD)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/pdf_file", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Add("content-type", "application/pdf")
        w.Write(file_bytes)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

this sends a pdf file in the browser. Maybe you send row pdf as a string that means encoding is wrong so a browser cannot parse that.